# Ansible: Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.command) module: warn

Tags: ansible

Today I encountered an old part of our Ansible playbook failing:

**Current situation**

```
- name: Install something
  shell: somecomand
  args:
    warn: false
```

This throws fatal:

```
"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.command) module: warn. Supported parameters include: chdir, _raw_params, removes, stdin, argv, executable, strip_empty_ends, stdin_add_newline, creates, _uses_shell."
```

Apparently `warn` is no longer supported. I tried to find the "new" way to ignore warnings, but everything I found directed me towards the old `warn: false` method.

**Question**

What is the "new" way to ignore warning or - if a better way comes to mind: to fix this issue?

**Ansible version**

```
pip show ansible
Name: ansible
Version: 7.0.0
Summary: Radically simple IT automation
Home-page: https://ansible.com/
Author: Ansible, Inc.
Author-email: info@ansible.com
License: GPLv3+
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: ansible-core
Required-by:
```

The same playbook runs without issues under:

```
pip show ansible
Name: ansible
Version: 6.6.0
Summary: Radically simple IT automation
Home-page: https://ansible.com/
Author: Ansible, Inc.
Author-email: info@ansible.com
License: GPLv3+
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: ansible-core
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `warn` parameter for `shell` was deprecated in Ansible 2.11 and removed in Ansible 2.14. You can check the following resources for more information:

- [Deprecated features in Ansible 2.11.0 changelog](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.11.0/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.11.rst#deprecated-features).
- [Pull request which deprecated the feature in Ansible 2.11](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/70504) *(Credit to [@U880D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771046/u880d) for the link)*

The fact that the module reported in the error message is different from the one actually used is weird. I did not look into the issue but it looks like some display bug (to be confirmed)

The `warn` argument to shell was once a way to silence annoying warnings like:

> You're using shell for XXX but there's a module for that. Are you sure you're not a bad boy?.

Checking those kind of good practice is done with [`ansible-lint`](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/) nowadays and [silencing warning there is done differently](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/usage/#muting-warnings-to-avoid-false-positives)

In conclusion, you have 2 choices at this point:

1. Downgrade to ansible-core 2.13.x. Since you are using the meta community package, the corresponding latest version is ansible 6.6.0 as you reported in your question.
2. Remove all the `warn` entries on all shell tasks in your code. As explained above.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Based on your writing I've found a comment on Ansible Issue #[77046](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70746#issuecomment-661936098) stating that "_we're deprecating the command warning feature entirely in 2.11+ ... and removing it in 2.14_" and referencing Ansible Pull #[70504](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/70504) "_Deprecate command warnings feature_".